# PHP downloading video files from server

Tags: javascript, php, download

User can stream videos from my site. i want to add a button so when user click on the button it will allow the browser to download the file,

How do i do that?

Retrieve video to stream

```
  if(isset($_POST['video_id'])){
        $id = trim($_POST['video_id']);
        //check if it exists
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc , "SELECT `video_id`, `video_link` FROM `viewvideo` WHERE `video_id`='".$video_id."'");
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        //does it exist?
        if($count>0){
            //exists, so fetch it in an associative array
            $video_arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            //this way you can use the column names to call out its values. 
            //If you want the link to the video to embed it;
            //echo "Video Link: ".$video_arr['video_link'];
            echo $video_arr['video_link'];
            ?>

        <div id="video">
            <video width="640" height="480" controls>
                <source src="<?php echo $video_arr['video_link']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
        </div>
```

Download button

```
<button id="download" onclick="download()">download</button>

function download() {
                    <?php
                     if(isset($_POST['video_id'])){
                // get the video link...
                $fileName=$video_arr['video_link'];
                $fileName=str_replace("..",".",$fileName); //required. if somebody is trying parent folder files
                $file = "../folder/".$fileName;
                if (file_exists($file)) {
                    $mime = 'application/force-download';

                    header('Content-Type: '.$mime);

                    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$fileName);
                    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                    header('Expires: 0');
                    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                    header('Pragma: public');
                    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
                    ob_clean();
                    flush();
                    readfile($file);
                    exit;
                    ?>
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a link tag somewhere, linking to your video file:

```
<a href='your-video.mp4' download>
```

Comment: It degrades gracefully into a normal link. Modern browsers will do the right thing. I'd just prefer that the OP doesn't try to do something crazy to get that result. But +1, it's a good tip ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can simply use download attribute of HTML like below

```
<a href="**YOUR FILE LINK**" download>Click here to Download</a>
```

This may be help you!

Answer (score 0):

As i already mentioned in a comment the download attribute doesn't work well in IE Browsers(tested it by myself! |  [Also on can i use](http://caniuse.com/#search=download)) .

Instead i would go with something like this:

```
          if(isset($_POST['video_id'])){
                // get the video link...
                $fileName=$video_arr['video_link'];
                $fileName=str_replace("..",".",$fileName); //required. if somebody is trying parent folder files
                $file = "../destinationOfYourFile/".$fileName;
                if (file_exists($file)) {
                    $mime = 'application/force-download';

                    header('Content-Type: '.$mime);

                    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$fileName);
                    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                    header('Expires: 0');
                    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                    header('Pragma: public');
                    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
                    ob_clean();
                    flush();
                    readfile($file);
                    exit;
                }
            }
```

**EDIT:**

HTML:

```
<button id="download" onclick="download()">download</button>
```

JS:

```
function download(){
    var fileName = FILENAME; // you need to get your filename, e.g. "video.mp4"
    window.location.href = 'https://www.YOURSITE.com/LOCATION/TO/download.php?filename=' + fileName;
}
```

download.php:

```
          if(isset($_GET['filename'])){
                $fileName=$_GET['filename'];
                $fileName=str_replace("..",".",$fileName); //required. if somebody is trying parent folder files
                $file = "../destinationOfYourFile/".$fileName; // you need to change the destination to your video folder
                if (file_exists($file)) {
                    $mime = 'application/force-download';

                    header('Content-Type: '.$mime);

                    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$fileName);
                    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                    header('Expires: 0');
                    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                    header('Pragma: public');
                    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
                    ob_clean();
                    flush();
                    readfile($file);
                    exit;
                }
            }
```

So you only need to change the paths i mentioned in the code and get your filename and everything should work fine. I hope i could help you :)

Comment: i placed this code inside the function but its not working? edit my post with the code

Comment: on the developer console it say download is not a function

Comment: solve the problem.. download is reserved so i changed to videodownload and got a new error now.. videodownload is not defined

Comment: The video still does not get downloaded.. when i click download a blank download.php page is shown no video is being download

Comment: is download.php finding your file?

Comment: Yes. i view it under sources using the developer tool. but it only display a blank page

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your web and database are in one server. Otherwise, implementation would be totally different or may be done through FTP.

**html**

If you are using bootstrap, you can easily transform anchor tag to button display. I recommend anchor tag over button for download links.

```
<a href="<?php echo 'http://baseurl/download_video.php?video_id='.$video_arr['video_id']; ?>">Download</a>
```

**php - download_video.php**

I recommend GET method over POST, since you will just be fetching data.

```
// query video info here using $_GET['video_id']
$filepath = $result['video_path'];
$filename = base_name($filepath);

// enable php_fileinfo.dll/.so in php.ini as necessary
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $filepath);
finfo_close($finfo);

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: ".$mime);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$fname."\"");

ob_clean();
flush();

readfile($filepath);                
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_url = $_GET['link'];           // http://www.somedomain.com/test.mp4
header('Content-Type: video/mp4'); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . 
basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);
```